# Python packages installation in Windows

Tags: python, pip, package, setuptools, distutils

I recently began learning Python, and I am a bit confused about how packages are distributed and installed.

I understand that the official way of installing packages is **distutils**: you download the source tarball, unpack it, and run: `python setup.py install`, then the module will automagically install itself

I also know about **setuptools** which comes with `easy_install` helper script. It uses **eggs** for distribution, and from what I understand, is built on top of distutils and does the same thing as above, plus it takes care of any dependencies required, all fetched from PyPi

Then there is also **pip**, which I'm still not sure how it differ from the others.

Finally, as I am on a windows machine, a lot of packages also offers binary builds through a **windows installer**, especially the ones that requires compiling C/Fortran code, which otherwise would be a nightmare to manually compile on windows (assumes you have MSVC or MinGW/Cygwin dev environment with all necessary libraries setup.. nonetheless try to build numpy or scipy yourself and you will understand!)

So can someone help me make sense of all this, and explain the differences, pros/cons of each method.  I'd like to know how each keeps track of packages (Windows Registry, config files, ..). In particular, how would you manage all your third-party libraries (be able to list installed packages, disable/uninstall, etc..)

Comment: Related: [Listing installed python site-packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300794/), [Can I install Python windows packages into virtualenvs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590/). The latter mentions *virtualenv* but it's valid outside of *virtualenv* as well.

Comment: This should be of interest to anyone who lands on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14753678/97160

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use pip, and not on Windows, so I can't provide comparison with the Windows-installer option, just some information about pip:

- Pip is built on top of setuptools, and requires it to be installed.
- Pip is a replacement (improvement) for setuptools' easy_install. It does everything easy_install does, plus a lot more (make sure all desired distributions can be downloaded before actually installing any of them to avoid broken installs, list installed distributions and versions, uninstall, search PyPI, install from a requirements file listing multiple distributions and versions...).
- Pip currently does not support installing any form of precompiled or binary distributions, so any distributions with extensions requiring compilation can only be installed if you have the appropriate compiler available. Supporting installation from Windows binary installers is on the roadmap, but it's not clear when it will happen.
- Until recently, pip's Windows support was flaky and untested. Thanks to a lot of work from Dave Abrahams, pip trunk now passes all its tests on Windows (and there's a continuous integration server helping us ensure it stays that way), but a release has not yet been made including that work. So more reliable Windows support should be coming with the next release.
- All the standard Python package installation mechanisms store all metadata about installed distributions in a file or files next to the actual installed package(s). Distutils uses a distribution_name-X.X-pyX.X.egg-info file, pip uses a similarly-named directory with multiple metadata files in it. Easy_install puts all the installed Python code for a distribution inside its own zipfile or directory, and places an EGG-INFO directory inside that directory with metadata in it. If you import a Python package from the interactive prompt, check the value of package.__file__; you should find the metadata for that package's distribution nearby.
- Info about installed distributions is only stored in any kind of global registry by OS-specific packaging tools such as Windows installers, Apt, or RPM. The standard Python packaging tools don't modify or pay attention to these listings.
- Pip (or, in my opinion, any Python packaging tool) is best used with [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), which allows you to create isolated per-project Python mini-environments into which you can install packages without affecting your overall system. Every new virtualenv automatically comes with pip installed in it.

A couple other projects you may want to be aware of as well (yes, there's more!):

- [distribute](http://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute) is a fork of setuptools which has some additional bugfixes and features.
- [distutils2](http://bitbucket.org/tarek/distutils2) is intended to be the "next generation" of Python packaging. It is (hopefully) adopting the best features of distutils/setuptools/distribute/pip. It is being developed independently and is not ready for use yet, but eventually should replace distutils in the Python standard library and become the de facto Python packaging solution.

Hope all that helped clarify something! Good luck.

Comment: thank you for the overview, that was helpful. One remark, looking at the `site-packages` directory, in addition to the expected, there's also a couple of `.pth` files which I assume are easy_install metadata?

Comment: @Amro: yes, because easy_install puts each distribution's Python code in a separate zipfile or directory, it has to do some sys.path hackery to make them all importable. setuptools.pth and easy-install.pth do that hackery.

Comment: I see, I guess this is necessary of we are to have multiple version of the same module without conflict.. Thanks again

Comment: @Amro: yes, that's right. Pip users tend to use virtualenv to avoid the need for side-by-side multi-version installs, since pip's installation style does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

I use windows and python. It is somewhat frustrating, because pip doesn't always work to install things. Python is moving to pip, so I still use it. Pip is nice, because you can uninstall items and use

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Another reason I like pip is for virtual environments like venv with python 3.4. I have found venv a lot easier to use on windows than virtualenv.

If you cannot install a package you have to find the binary for it. http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

I have found these binaries to be very useful.

Pip is trying to make something called a wheel for binary installations.

```
pip install wheel
wheel convert path\to\binary.exe
pip install converted_wheel.whl
```

You will also have to do this for any required libraries that do not install and are required for that package.