# Can I install Python windows packages into virtualenvs?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

Virtualenv is great: it lets me keep a number of distinct Python installations so that different projects' dependencies aren't all thrown together into a common pile.

But if I want to install a package on Windows that's packaged as a .exe installer, how can I direct it to install into the virtualenv?  For example, I have pycuda-0.94rc.win32-py2.6.exe.  When I run it, it examines the registry, and finds only one Python26 to install into, the common one that my virtualenv is based off of.

How can I direct it to install into the virtualenv?

Comment: the answer below works for me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114115/windows-virtualenv-pip-numpy-problems-when-installing-numpy

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I ended up adapting a script (http://effbot.org/zone/python-register.htm) to register a Python installation in the registry.  I can pick the Python to be *the* Python in the registry, run the Windows installer, then set the registry back:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
#
# script to register Python 2.0 or later for use with win32all
# and other extensions that require Python registry settings
#
# Adapted by Ned Batchelder from a script
# written by Joakim Löw for Secret Labs AB / PythonWare
#
# source:
# http://www.pythonware.com/products/works/articles/regpy20.htm

import sys

from _winreg import *

# tweak as necessary
version = sys.version[:3]
installpath = sys.prefix

regpath = "SOFTWARE\\Python\\Pythoncore\\%s\\" % (version)
installkey = "InstallPath"
pythonkey = "PythonPath"
pythonpath = "%s;%s\\Lib\\;%s\\DLLs\\" % (
    installpath, installpath, installpath
)

def RegisterPy():
    try:
        reg = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regpath)
    except EnvironmentError:
        try:
            reg = CreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regpath)
        except Exception, e:
            print "*** Unable to register: %s" % e
            return

    SetValue(reg, installkey, REG_SZ, installpath)
    SetValue(reg, pythonkey, REG_SZ, pythonpath)
    CloseKey(reg)
    print "--- Python %s at %s is now registered!" % (version, installpath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RegisterPy()
```

Run this script with the Python you want to be registered, and it will be entered into the registry. Note that on Windows 7 and Vista, you'll need Administrator privileges.

Comment: On Windows 7, 64 bit, with 64 bit Python had to modify regpath to `regpath = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Python\\Pythoncore\\%s\\" % (version)`

Comment: Actually for my windows 7 , 64 bit, I left the regpath as is and it worked. The mod @Oleksiy suggested did not work.  Probably some subtle different in our OS version, or some setting.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder's solution was the only one that worked for me.  The wheel installation did not work. I still received package download errors (see my comment on that answer for more detail).  The suggestion to do the easy_install binary_installer... may have worked but I was not able to get easy_install to find the binary_installer...exe file.

Answer (score 201):

Yes, you can. All you need is

> easy_install
>   binary_installer_built_with_distutils.exe

Surprised? It looks like binary installers for Windows made with distutils combine .exe with .zip into one .exe file. Change extension to .zip to see it's a valid zip file. I discovered this after reading answers to my question [Where can I download binary eggs with psycopg2 for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382801/)

UPDATE

As noted by Tritium21 in his answer nowadays you should use pip instead of easy_install. Pip can't install binary packages created by distutils but it can install binary packages in the new [wheel](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) format. You can convert from old format to the new one using [wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) package, which you have to install first.

Comment: I agree, this is great.  By the way, if you have 7zip, you can open the .exe directly, without having to rename it as zip.

Comment: just a tip: developers can download various built python packages for windows from  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ .

Comment: @CodyHatch You can as this is not my only answer on SO and there's a chance some of my other answers would be helpful to you as well :)

Comment: I get the following: Searching for binary-installer-built-with-distutils.exe Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/binary_installer_built_with_distutils.exe/
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/binary-installer-built-with-distutils.exe/
Couldn't find index page for 'binary_installer_built_with_distutils.exe' Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for binary-installer-built-with-distutils.exe error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('binary-instal
ler-built-with-d...

Comment: Paul, the exe he's referring to will be different depending on which installer you're using...not literally "binary-installer-built-with-distutils.exe"

Comment: How would one do this on OSX?

Comment: it should be pointed out that there are some serious drawbacks to using easy_install, including security, the inability to use wheels (the new format that actually is a standard), increased import time (eggs do some whacky things - installing a lot of them slows down the import process dramatically.)

Answer (score 71):

I know this is quite an old question, and predates the tools I am about to talk about, but for the sake of Google, I think it is a good idea to mention it.  easy_install is the black sheep of python packaging.  No one wants to admit using it with the new hotness of pip around.  Also, while playing registry tricks will work best for non-standard EXE installers (someone built the installer themselves instead of using distutils, and is checking the registry for the installation path), there is now a Better Way(c) for standard EXE installers.

```
pip install wheel
wheel convert INSTALLER.EXE
pip install NEW_FILE_CREATED_IN_LAST_STEP.whl
```

The wheel format, introduced recently as of this post, is the replacement for the egg format, filling much the same role.  This format is also supported by pip (a tool already installed in your virtualenv).

if for some reason `pip install WHEELFILE` does not work, try `wheel install WHEELFILE`

Comment: Thanks for this.  Hopefully more people notice your answer and upvote!

Comment: To be clear. You can create a .whl from a .exe, for example from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, with this. This is HUGE im terms of deployment!

Comment: I tried to do this, but got an error wheel convert numpy-MKL-1.8.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe  then pip install numpy-1.8.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl i get the following error Downloading/unpacking numpy-1.8.1-cp27-none-win-amd64.whl
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement numpy-1.8.1-cp27-non
e-win-amd64.whl
No distributions at all found for numpy-1.8.1-cp27-none-win-amd64.whl

Comment: try ``wheel install WHEELFILE``, answer edited to point out the existence of that.  Debugging a specific problem for someone is not something trivially done in SO comments.

Comment: After needing easy_install so many times for only this purpose, that was beautiful. *tearfully waves goodbye to easy_install

Answer (score 7):

easy_install is able to install .exe packages as long as they were built using distutils' bdist_wininst target, which covers many popular packages. However, there are many others that aren't (wxPython is one that I've struggled with)

Comment: Yes, and as long as you've installed whatever development package of all the dependencies.  In my case pycuda needs Boost and CUDA, not a trivial undertaking.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder *Yes, and as long as you've installed whatever development package of all the dependencies.* Well, binary installer doesn't install all dependencies neither, does it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment's easy_install to install PyCUDA.

```
dev-env-path/bin/easy_install pycuda
```

it will give you the same version 0.94rc.

On Windows easy_install.exe will be in Scripts directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will try to build from source.  I was hoping to use pre-built binaries.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a `.msi`, you might be able to specify command line options using `msiexec`.  The Python [installer](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5/msi/) itself allows `TARGETDIR`, but I'm not sure if distutils bakes this into distribution installers.

If you're using a `.exe`, I don't think there's a clean way.  One option is to use a program like 7Zip (or winzip, etc) to directly extract the contents of the exe, then copy the relevent folders into your virtual site-packages folder.  For example, if I extract "processing-0.5.2.win32-py2.5.exe", I find a folder "PLATLIB\processing" which I copy to a virtualenv path and use without any runtime problems.  (I'm not sure it's always that simple though.)

Answer (score 0):

You should type path of your file and write 'python ' before it.

Than it will run your python script without any virtual environment.

Thanks.