# What are the pitfalls and workarounds when using Python virtual environments on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

**Short Description**
The question is not meant to ask if using virtual environments are needed, but when using Ian Bicking's [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org)  what is the best way, if any, to manage environments in Windows.  If you have multiple ideas, please answer multiple times so the best answers can be voted up.  Thanks!

**Background**
When developing in python, I generally try use Mac osx / bash as much as possible. However there are always projects that I am forced to use Windows on for hardware/driver support.  For these projects, I tend to rely on the 'double click' method to run the modules with the registered python.exe.  The use of the 'double click' is such a simple way to run multiple threads / tests at the same time, without having to open a new command prompt, drill down to the directory needed, then typing 'python.exe module.py'.

**The End Goal**
I would like to have a way to manage and utilize virtual environments without having to be at the command prompt (Windows only)

**Wish List**
1. Be able to install modules from either pip (command line) or from binaries (for those that can't be installed with pip for whatever reason).
2. Manage environments, with virtualenv.exe,  from a GUI. (Create, remove, list, activate, etc...)

**Research**
So far I have been able to do bits and pieces of my wish list using different scripts / methods, but have yet to find a way to combine them.  I was planning to combine most of these into a GUI my self, but thought it would be wise to find out if there is a *good* reason this doesn't exist already.

Installing binaries to a virtual environment can be done fairly easy using a script that changes what version of python is registered in Windows.  I have been using the script for several months now with nothing but great results. See [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590)

Managing the environments appears to the more difficult portion.

If using bash, there is [virutalenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) written by Doug Hellmann.  I use this when working in Mac OSX and hightly recommend it.

There is a port of this exertion into Power Shell found [here](https://bitbucket.org/vanl/virtualenvwrapper-powershell)  but still will require a third party command prompt interface to be installed.

One of the more unique ports to windows that I have seen ports virtualenvwrapper to bat files.  I have not tested this, but it would still require a the use of the command prompt.  Found [here](https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win)

The most promising helper function I have found to date is written by Justin Driscoll.  While [this](http://justindriscoll.us/2009/03/virtualenv-helper-for-windows.html) exact example would require the command prompt, it would be trivial to convert this to something that a python GUI could call.  This was the path I was going down before I thought I should check with the masses on the best way to achieve my goal.

Comment: It seems like you could effectively use .bat files to accomplish this task, but I guess I'm not sure what you mean about "without having to be at the command prompt."  A batch file would let you automate your command line input, and you could integrate it with a Windows Script or JScript file if you needed more functionality. The usage examples on Justin Driscoll's page could be put into a batch file that you could then just double-click. I know it's not exactly a GUI, but it would allow you to centralize your parameters/variables. Is that what you are thinking of?  Or have I missed the gist?

Comment: @ Kit:  If you wouldn't mind add this as an answer, it is close to the functionality I am searching for.  I'll add more comments when it's an answer (So it can benefit others as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [zc.buildout](http://www.buildout.org/). Assuming the user has Python installed, you can double click on the `bootstrap.py` python script to generate the environment.

Once created, doubleclicking on `bin\buildout.exe` will recursively install dependencies and run any pre/post hook methods you define. zc.buildout allows you to specify platform specific dependencies and non-python dependencies. Additionally, you may define your own scripts for buildout to place into the `bin\` folder. For example, the [Plone](http://plone.org/) team has a good article running [Buildout on Windows](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/buildout-using-windows-installer) referencing their own script `bin\instance.exe`

While not quite a polished as virtualenv on Mac/Linux/BSD, the same buildout environment will be created (eg. `bin/buildout` instead of `bin\buildout.exe`) achieving the cross-platform requirements you have.

Comment: I have never seen buildout before.  After looking into it, I can see it's uses over all for deploying software.  However I'm afraid I don't see it's strengths for developing software.  That's the real strength I am looking for in virtualenv.  On any given day, I can be working on 3 vastly different projects (each with their own python dependencies).  Thanks for the info though!

Comment: Buildout can isolate you from your system packages similar to how virtualenv works.  For example I will run a bin/python executable (bin is inside my project dir structure).  That python will only have access to eggs inside my project dir.  It achieves a similar effect as virtualenv.  It is a bit more of a pain, and has the big win of super easy deployment. Choices, choices...

Comment: @Brian: Thank you for that clarification.  I will look into it again with that mind set.