# Can I install Python 2.7.1 64bit along side of an exsiting 32bit install on OS X?

Tags: python, django, macos, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

**Short Description**
Is it possible to install Python 2.7.1 64/32bit from [python.org](http://www.python.org/download/#id11) on top of an existing install (from python.org) of Python 2.7.1 32bit?

**Background**
I installed the 32bit version for wxPython(2.8) support which until now has given me zero issues.  There are a few modules that I am now having difficultly installing (psycopg2 and mysql-python).  The warning messages in homebrew constantly warn me about not having a 64bit version of Python on the path.  These warnings only add to my list of wanting to use a 64 bit version.

At the time I selected the 32bit install, the GUI for a particular project was the main focus.  Now the GUI has been come very simple and the database back-end support (using Django) is much more important.  This being said, using the development version of wxPython 2.9 (which supports OS X and 64bit 2.7) has become acceptable.

For the non-mac users, to help explain why I had to use the 32bit version please see this [Brief guide to using virtualenv in a wxpython project](http://batok.github.com/virtualenvwxp/)

**System Information**
*Development System*
*OS:* Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.7)
*Python:* 2.7.1 with virutalenv / virutalenv-wrapper
*Project Dependencies:*
Note that MySQL could be PostgresSQL's psycopg2 if I can get the postgresql to install with homebrew

> Django==1.2.5
>   MySQL-python==1.2.3
>   PIL==1.1.7
>   PyVISA==1.3
>   pyserial==2.5
>   virtualenv==1.5.1
>   virtualenvwrapper==2.6.3
>   wsgiref==0.1.2
>   wxPython==2.8.11.0
>   wxPython-common==2.8.11.0

*Deployment System*
*OS:* Windows XP / Windows 7
*Python:* Hopefully none (goal to use py2exe, or similar tool)

**Current Thoughts**
I fear that my goal cannot be accomplished based on the file paths alone.  In Windows 7 the identifier (x86) is placed in the path showing that it is a 32bit program, but on OS X the path would be the same for 32bit or 64/32bit installs (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/).

Any thoughts or comments would be helpful!

**Update 5-18-2011: 8:40 AM**
I have confirmed that using the pre-compiled (.dmg) framework builds, installing the a 64 bit version *does* blow away the 32 bit install.  This did negatively effect my virtual environments in that all of the things I have installed in the environments was based on the 32 bit install nearly every module threw an error of some sort.

I still have not achieved installing 32 bit and 64 bit on the same machine, however looking into [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) with greater detail does look this *could* be possible.  The trick would be to define your own formulas for each of the python builds (from source) and rename the install directory to something like 'Python27_32' and 'Python27_64'.  I'll keep exploring this front as I have time.

**EDIT 7-12-2011: 10:51 AM CST**
Has anyone out there been able control how homebrew compile options?  Specifically how to select to use a 64bit compiler or a 32 bit compiler?  I will create a new SO question if this doesn't bring anything up.

Comment: This may be of no help, I've not compiled python on a mac, but if you build from source, you can just pass the configure script the --prefix option which tells the make system where you want the compiled version installed. Just set the --prefix option to a different path than where your current version of python is installed.

Comment: @tMC: I have never built a Python distro from source, so I am reluctant to do this.  However I see that this thought might work well using something like homebrew to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with homebrew- but if during your tinkering you see an the option 'prefix' thats what it means.  I know mac ports has a build system and I imagine you can specify the build options for it during the configure. FWIW

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.macports.org/   Which provides ports of various flavors of linux/unix tools that don't appear in the default MacInstallation and duplicates those that it needs otherwise.  It installs everthing in /opt/local instead of stepping on the installed base.  With some manipulation of PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH this might give you the options you need.

Comment: I'm afraid I am already using homebrew (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) so switching to Macports isn't that feasible for me.  However the thought on using the localized installs might be possible.  I will have to look into the availability of Python ditros there.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). This way you can have as many different installs of python as you wish.

EDIT: To use different versions of python use:

```
virtualenv -p python2.6
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv/1534343#1534343)

Comment: I am currently using virtualenv on OS X and Win 7.  Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't virtualenv is designed to manage site-package isolation not Python (as in 2.x, 3.x, etc...) installs?  At the moment, I have Python 2.7 installed and virtualenv uses it for all of it's environments.

Comment: Here's how you use different versions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv/1534343#1534343

Comment: I understand using different python versions with different environments (I use 2.6 and 2.7 on my Win7 box).  The issue I am having is installing those versions of python (which virtualenv uses)

Comment: That's pretty much what Andrew has said.  Check out my comment I left him.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that was provided in an answer to [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887018) aimed at using a virtual environment in the Windows world was using [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/).  This approach looks like it would allow me create an environment with the 32bit installed and another one with the 64bit.

I have not tested this out yet, but wanted to pass it along to anyone else attempting this feat.

Cheers!