# Will 32bit and 64bit Python collide?

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit, python-2.7, vpython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Python 2.7.1 64bit along side of an exsiting 32bit install on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032440/can-i-install-python-2-7-1-64bit-along-side-of-an-exsiting-32bit-install-on-os-x)

I have a MacBook Pro running 10.7.3 Lion with Python 2.7 64bit installed by default. I need a program called VPython for a physics class I am in and VPython site says it doesnt work with 64 bit Python. So I was wondering if i had both 32 bit and 64bit Python 2.7 on my MacBook, if they would collide or cause problems. I know i could do Python 3.1 version of VPython, but I think most of the instructions the professor gives us is for Python 2.7. Thanks for any help regarding this.

Comment: Ok that didnt help at all. And I dont try it, bc if it messes something up, I dont want to spend time getting it back to the way it was. Bc i just redid my computer 3 times in the past week.

Comment: Now that did help.. LOL I didnt find that in my search or when i typed the title of this post in. But that explained maybe how to work around it. Thanks for that

Comment: No problem.  It was hit #6 for "installing 32-bit python and 64-bit python".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without installing another python you can switch between the default 32/64 bits using env:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'
9223372036854775807
$ export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'
2147483648
```

See `man python` on OSX.

You can also execute the binary with `arch -i386`:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7 -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'
9223372036854775807
$ arch -i386 /usr/bin/python2.7 -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'
2147483648
```