# Is it possible to use "exe installers" with pip?

Tags: python, pip

It's possible with easy_install to install exes from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Is there a way to do the same thing with pip?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I install Python windows packages into virtualenvs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590/can-i-install-python-windows-packages-into-virtualenvs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because I found this question earlier than the better answer in [Can I install Python windows packages into virtualenvs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590/can-i-install-python-windows-packages-into-virtualenvs): there is now a way to convert exe installer into wheels which then can be installed via pip. The link has the details.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think this is possible with pip, but this can be done with [easy_install](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html). e.g.

```
$ easy_install -U -Z "exe_installer_path"
```

**--upgrade, -U**
**--always-unzip, -Z**

For further explanation of the command line options please take a look [here.](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html#command-line-options)

Comment: It's 2014 and in some cases still `easy_install > pip`. Sometimes you're stuck in Windows, with no admin privileges, and all you have to install a package is this.

Answer (score 6):

No, with `pip` it is not possible to install an `.exe` file. These `.exe` files provided are installer scripts themselves and should be managed by the operating system itself.

Comment: Don't they work with easy_install? I tried and it seems they get installed in the right place in a virtualenv.

Comment: pip does not support everything easy_install does. pip basically install source packages (tarball, zip, folders, etc).