# How does Python package installer exe work?

Tags: python, setuptools

The setuptools installer for Windows 7 x86 is named an exe file, but can be opened as a zip file.  When I peek into it, there are two top level folders: PURELIB and SCRIPTS.  What are these, and how is it that when I double click on this exe, Windows runs it for me, although it's a zip file?  That is, how does Windows know what to run inside this zip/exe?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  How does bdist_wininst installer get called when the exe/zip is double clicked?  Wait!  You maintain the pre-built exe's that are so useful, thank you so much for those.

Comment: Related: [Can I install Python windows packages into virtualenvs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3271590/95735)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are these, and how is it that when I double click on this exe,
>   Windows runs it for me, although it's a zip file?

From http://zziplib.sourceforge.net/sfx-make.html

> The basic scheme goes like this: the final file will have an EXE
>   starting at offset null, followed by the data entries of a ZIP
>   archive. The last part of the ZIP archive is the ZIP central-directory
>   which ends at the end of the file.

The *magic* is possible because exe format allows any data to be appended to the executable and zip format allows any data to be prepended to the archive.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [self-extracting archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive).

> A self-extracting archive is a computer application which contains a
>   file archive, as well as programming to extract this information. Such
>   file archives do not require a second executable file or program to
>   extract from the archive, as archive files usually require. The files
>   in an archive can thus be extracted by anyone, whether they possess
>   the appropriate decompression program or not, as long as the program
>   can run on their computer platform.

It is an executable, it's just that your extraction software knows to look for self-extracting archives, and treats it as a normal archive.

Comment: I am aware of the self-extraction concept, was looking for further details re: how these two folders interact with the installer.

Comment: @Sabuncu 'That's entirely up to the program that generated the self-extracting archive. There is no standard for it.