# Installing gevent in virtualenv

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, gevent

I am just starting with virtualenv, but I am trying to install [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) within a virtualenv environment (I am running Windows). When I use PIP from virtualenv, I get this error:

```
MyEnv>pip install gevent
Downloading/unpacking gevent
  Running setup.py egg_info for package gevent
    Please provide path to libevent source with --libevent DIR
```

The package index has MSIs and EXEs for installing on Windows (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent/0.13.7), but I don't know how to install those into a virtualenv environment (or if that is even possible). When I try `pip install gevent-0.13.7.win32-py2.7.exe` from the virtualenv promp, I get an error as well:

```
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'D:\\Downloads\\gevent-0.13.7.win32-py2.7.exe', 'at', ':\\Downloads\\gevent-0.13.7.win32-py2.7.exe')
```

Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pip doesn't support installing binary packages, yet. If you want to install from binary package you have to use easy_install - `easy_install gevent-0.13.7.win32-py2.7.exe`

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Wersja 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

Z:\>virtualenv z:\venv\gevent-install
New python executable in z:\venv\gevent-install\Scripts\python.exe
Installing distribute..................................................................................................
............................................................................................done.
Installing pip.................done.

Z:\>venv\gevent-install\Scripts\activate
(gevent-install) Z:\>easy_install c:\python\packages\gevent-0.13.7.win32-py2.7.exe
Processing gevent-0.13.7.win32-py2.7.exe
creating 'c:\docume~1\pdobro~1\ustawi~1\temp\easy_install-b5nj3i\gevent-0.13.7-py2.7-win32.egg' and adding 'c:\docume~1
pdobro~1\ustawi~1\temp\easy_install-b5nj3i\gevent-0.13.7-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp' to it
creating z:\venv\gevent-install\lib\site-packages\gevent-0.13.7-py2.7-win32.egg
Extracting gevent-0.13.7-py2.7-win32.egg to z:\venv\gevent-install\lib\site-packages
Adding gevent 0.13.7 to easy-install.pth file

Installed z:\venv\gevent-install\lib\site-packages\gevent-0.13.7-py2.7-win32.egg
Processing dependencies for gevent==0.13.7
Searching for greenlet
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/greenlet/
Reading http://bitbucket.org/ambroff/greenlet
Reading https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet
Best match: greenlet 0.3.4
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/g/greenlet/greenlet-0.3.4-py2.7-win32.egg#md5=9941aa246358c586bb274812e
130629
Processing greenlet-0.3.4-py2.7-win32.egg
creating z:\venv\gevent-install\lib\site-packages\greenlet-0.3.4-py2.7-win32.egg
Extracting greenlet-0.3.4-py2.7-win32.egg to z:\venv\gevent-install\lib\site-packages
Adding greenlet 0.3.4 to easy-install.pth file

Installed z:\venv\gevent-install\lib\site-packages\greenlet-0.3.4-py2.7-win32.egg
Finished processing dependencies for gevent==0.13.7

(gevent-install) Z:\>
```

See [Can I install Python windows packages into virtualenvs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590/) Another option is to install from source and you can do this with pip but this requires setting up compiler and environment which is much harder than the simple command above.

Comment: It still ends with `error: Setup script exited with Please provide path to libevent source with --libevent DIR`

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it would appear you need libevent source code.  I would imagine you need to go a step further and compile/install libevent system-wide so pip can find it.

1. I would start by downloading the latest stable source from http://libevent.org/.
2. Compile and install it using instructions in the README: https://github.com/libevent/libevent#readme

To compile it on Windows, you'll need to use GNU-style build utilities like `make` and `autoconf`. I recommend http://www.mingw.org/.

Once you've installed libevent system-wide, I imagine pip will find it and proceed with `gevent` installation.

Answer (score 0):

In the msi for gevent-0.13.7 there's an option to select an alternate installation point.  point it to the root dir of your particular virtual environment (just above where /Lib and /Scripts are located).  That should install it correctly.

You also need to make sure [greenlets](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet) are installed.  For that you can use Piotr's suggested method with easy_install on the .exe.