# Installing Python binary modules to a custom location in Windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, package, distutils

Suppose that I want to install a binary module for Python on Windows. Suppose that the module is distributed as a pre-built installer `xxx-n.n.n.win32-py2.7.exe`, prepared using distutils.

My problem is that the installer insists on installing the package into whatever Python directory he finds in the registry. However, I have this tiny "portable" Python directory on a flash drive that I use from time to time and need to have packages installed there. That directory is not marked in the registry.

So far what I was doing was simply unpacking the installer and manually copying the files into `Lib/site-packages`. But perhaps there is a smarter alternative? Could I hack the distutils installer somehow to let me specify the target Python directory (as some other installers do)?

PS: Note that easy-install is not an option, as it insists on compiling packages from source, whereas I want to install the precompiled package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I install Python windows packages into virtualenvs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590/can-i-install-python-windows-packages-into-virtualenvs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **can** install binary packages using easy_install and it doesn't require compilation:

`easy_install binary_installer_built_with_distutils.exe`

See [Can I install Python windows packages into virtualenvs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590/)