# Unable to install python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I need to create table in a Word document through Python 3.4. For that, I am trying to install `python-docx` in Windows. If I use `pip install python-docx` I am getting the following error:

```
vcvarsall.bat error
```

So I installed Visual Studio and then tried to install it and I am still getting the following :

```
error: Setup script exited with error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: ...any other error messages? Have you tried to find a prebuilt version for your OS?

Comment: No.. how is that ? Any other option to print the output in table format using python 3.4 ?

Comment: `vcvarsall.bat` is a Microsoft C++ compiler. The error means that `setuptools` can't find a compiler installed on your machine. Normally, I find a Windows binary and use [this command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711878/1394393), but without an existing Windows binary, you might have to build from source yourself.

Comment: Hang on. It looks like the native dependency might be `lxml`. If so, the error comes from installing `lxml`, *not* `python-docx`. What happens if you install `lxml` from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) using the command I mentioned above before installing `python-docx`?

Comment: Possible dupe of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2817869)

Answer (score 14):

This is a problem with the `lxml` install. If you install `lxml` separately, using a Windows binary package, then reinstall python-docx, this error should go away.

You can find a binary `lxml` package here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Comment: Since this worked for you, please accept the answer and click the up-arrow to endorse it if it was a help :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was not able to install the lxml wheel for 64 machine because python falsely identifies my computer as 32. Ultimately installed the 32 and then it installed python-docx successfully.
FYI: I would have added this to comments but I don’t have the 50 required reputation to do so.

Comment: When trying to install either the 32-bit or the 64-bit version of the .whl files with pip in Windows 10 I get an error message saying that the .whl **is not a supported wheel on this platform.**

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the py-docx module from the official website: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-docx
2. Unzip it
3. Open the command prompt and change your directory to the unzipped file. There a file named setup.py will be present.
4. Type the following code in the command prompt window.

   ```
   setup.py install
   ```
5. The docx module is installed.

Answer (score 0):

In cas somebody is still struggling with this topic in version 3.7:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pl/downloads/
Scroll down and install:  Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

This worked fro me:

```
pip uninstall docx
pip uninstall lxml
pip install lxml
pip install python-docx
```

following this [git-hub discussion](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/405)

Answer (score 0):

Or, just download the .whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml as @scanny mentioned, then use pip to install it:

CMD environment:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install C:\Python27\Scripts\python_docx-0.8.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```