# Why I get "C extension could not be compiled" when installing simplejson?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, python-extensions

btw, i am using windows, so do i have to install visual studio?

```
(py) D:\python>pip install simplejson
Downloading/unpacking simplejson
  Downloading simplejson-2.6.2.tar.gz (53kB): 53kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package simplejson

Installing collected packages: simplejson
  Running setup.py install for simplejson
    building 'simplejson._speedups' extension
    ***************************************************************************
```

**WARNING: The C extension could not be compiled, speedups are not enabled.**

```
    Failure information, if any, is above.
    I'm retrying the build without the C extension now.



    ***************************************************************************

    ***************************************************************************
    WARNING: The C extension could not be compiled, speedups are not enabled.
    Plain-Python installation succeeded.
    ***************************************************************************
Successfully installed simplejson
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 3):

To be able to compile Python C extension modules on Windows you need the right version of Visual Studio installed. See [Building C and C++ Extensions on Windows](http://docs.python.org/extending/windows.html).

Comment: @hugemeow Grab already compiled package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and install it using `easy_install` after reading my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590/ question.

Comment: i need pysqlite-2.7.3 which is not provided by http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pysqlite

Comment: There's no 2.7.3 version of pysqlite; 2.6.3 is the newest and Windows' binary is available both at http://code.google.com/p/pysqlite/downloads/list and at http://lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs

Comment: do you know how to build sqlite support for python on linux?

Comment: If you already have sqlite installed (including headers) then `pip install pysqlite` should do the job.

Comment: i have sqlite installed, but that don't means i have python's sqlite extension, maybe that is just kind of sqlite.a in lib dir, without this lib, pip install pysqlite will fail..

Answer (score 1):

This is because simplejson obviously contains some C extension code to offset some of the processing this increases speed and efficiency, but the person was kind enough to provide a pure python alternative for machines that cannot compile c extensions of python code. The same is seen with other modules like SQLAlchemy and hiredis