# Installing msi files into virtualenv pythons on windows

Tags: python, windows

So have created a .reg file that will change where the system believes python is installed so that I can run an msi and install that into the intended virtualenv.  This works but is cumbersome.

But everytime I run a python .msi installer, I see this option to "Choose a python" from a rather large list box that only has one entry.  What would be really sweet would be to be able to pick my virtual environments from that list instead of having to load one .reg file to set it to the desired VirtualENV, then another to point it back at that system python that all the virtualenvs come from.

What registry entries can I create so that I have multiple 2.7 Pythons in those "Choose a python" lists I see during msi installation?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to manipulate the registry because you can use binary installer (.exe) to install Python package into virtualenv. See [Can I install Python windows packages into virtualenvs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3271590/95735) for details.

Comment: That's what I'm doing with .reg files.  Just seems like I should be able to register multiple Python 2.7's and pick them from that great big window where it asks me to "Choose a python" instead of having to swap the "real" python in and out.

Comment: @Mark0978 I'm not sure what's your point. You don't need .reg files because you can install into virtualenv using `easy_install binary_installer.exe` command. This way you don't run installer at all so there's no list to choose from.

Comment: @Mark0978 How do you find my latest comment?

Comment: I solved this problem by getting rid of windows.  All our web server work runs on linux anyway and the headache of dealing with it under windows was no longer worth it.  I'll give it a try on a windows vm and see how it plays out.