# Error installing pyv8 on virtualenv on Windows

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pyv8

I'm trying to install the pyv8 package on a virtualenv on Windows.

Here is what I did:

```
virtualenv venv
venv\Scripts\activate
pip install pyv8
```

and the last command failed with the following error:

```
File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
File "<proj_path>\venv\build\pyv8\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    include_dirs += os.environ["INCLUDE"].split(';')
File "<proj_path>\venv\lib\os.py", line 423, in __getitem__
    return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'INCLUDE'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an [executable](https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/downloads/list) that installs it for you on windows.

When you install it, be sure to point the installation directory to your virtualenv directory. You might also want to check out [this repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590/can-i-install-python-windows-packages-into-virtualenvs)