# Pip install - Could not find suitable distribution for requirement.parse()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install `pynotify` for python 2.7 using Pip. I am doing this in Windows Powershell. I can looked around for a solution but have been unsuccessful. I am using windows 7.

My code:

```
Pip install pynotify
```

Error:

```
No local packages or download links found for binary-installer-built-with-distutils.exe
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('binary-installer-built-with-distutils.exe')
```

I tried to install  binary_installer_built_with_distutils.exe with easy_install:

```
easy_install  binary_installer_built_with_distutils.exe
```

I get the following error message:

```
Couldn't find index page for 'binary_installer_built_with_distutils.exe' (maybe misspelled?)
```

Comment: Try installing distutils? Also, python development is a huge pain in Windows. I would suggest saving yourself the trouble early and just running *nix for development.

Comment: Did you have a look at this question already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590/can-i-install-python-windows-packages-into-virtualenvs

Comment: @cel, yes I did. I don't follow it all as I am new to programming and Python. I tried `easy_install inary_installer_built_with_distutils.exe` as someone suggested in there. Updated OP with error that yielded.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I tried installing it and added that to the original post. I'll look into nix but it doesn't seem like a super quick change to make.

Comment: @user2242044 That's not how you do that: https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/introduction.html