# Install python-igraph with the anaconda distribution (windows)

Tags: python, igraph, anaconda

I have problems to install python-igraph on the anaconda distribution of python.

If I write `pip install python-igraph` (with the admin privileges) in the anaconda command, the installation doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation on their site: http://igraph.org/python/
It says that you need to download the .msi installer, pip does not work under windows. That is probably because you need a C compiler and windows does not supply one by default.

Answer (score 4):

You can download a wheel installer from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-igraph and then install that wheel in your environment via

```
conda install pip
pip install *.whl
```

See this stackoverflow answer for ways to convert a *.exe into a wheel which can be installed as above: [Can I install Python windows packages into virtualenvs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590/can-i-install-python-windows-packages-into-virtualenvs)

Comment: it doesn't work, it says : python_igraph-0.7.1.post6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.