# How do I execute codes locally in a virtual environment using virtualenv in Python?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I first entered the following codes,

```
mkdir project #create a directory on current path called project
cd project
virtualenv my_env #create a virtual enviroment called my_env under directory project 
my_env\Scripts\activate.bat #activate my_env
```

then I tried

```
pip install requests
```

turns out package requests is created in the local environment, i.e., under path ...project\env\Lib\site-packages, however, I saw in a python tutorial that this code would actually create requests globally, and in order to create requests locally, one needs to use

```
my_env\Scripts\pip.exe install requests
```

So I wonder why `pip install requests` also performs locally in my case? Is the tutorial wrong? You can refer to the tutorial at http://thepythonguru.com/python-virtualenv-guide/

Comment: I don't understand.  You say you would need to use `my_env\Scripts\activate.bat`, but in your first example you *did* use `my_env\Scripts\activate.bat`.  So what is it that happened that you find unexpected?

Comment: try running `my_env\Scripts\deactivate.bat` and then running `import requests` in a Python shell.  I doubt it will work, because from what you've described it sounds like you've set up your virtual environment and activated it correctly.  To get back in the env, simply run `my_env\Scripts\activate.bat` again.

Comment: @BrenBarn, it should be "my_env\Scripts\pip.exe install requests" as the tutorial suggests. Sorry for the typo. I just corrected this mistake.

Comment: @cderwin, please reread my question, I made a typo and sorry for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install Python windows packages into virtualenvs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271590/can-i-install-python-windows-packages-into-virtualenvs)

Comment: The question's not asking if he can, he's asking why it works the way it does (in particular about how activate changes the PATH).  Not a duplicate for that question IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your operating system (in this case windows) searches for an executable when it's not given it's path (like `pip`), it searches each of the directories in the `PATH` environment variable for that executable (i.e. say you enter the command `python3` when

```
PATH="C:\Python27\bin;C:\Program Files\git\bin;
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\JDK\6.0\bin;C:\Python35\bin"
```

then the command line will search each of those directories for an executable name `python3`.  However, it won't find the executable until it searches the last directory, and then it will run `C:\Python35\bin\python3.exe`.

When you install a virtual environment (venv, for short) a script is created called `C:/path/to/my/venv/bin/activate.bat` which you can run to *activate* (what a surprise!) the *venv*.  Among other things, that script *prepends* `C:\path\to\my\venv\bin` to the `PATH` (i.e. sets `PATH="C:\path\to\my\venv\bin;$PATH`, where the dollar sign just means use the value of the `PATH` variable.

Then, when you ran `pip install requests`, the command line started to search the PATH for a pip executable.  It tries entries in order, so it found `pip.exe` in the `C:\path\to\my\venv\bin` directory, so in fact you *did* inadvertently use `C:\path\to\my\venv\bin\pip.exe` when you ran `pip install requests`.  More importantly, this is actua;;y one of the main purposes the `activate.bat` script exists; this way, you don't need to specify the precise path to every executable you have installed in you venv instead of using `C:\path\to\my\venv\bin\python` you can just use `python`, **so long as you activate the venv**.  If you never run `C:\path\to\my\venv\bin\activate.bat` then the `PATH` environment variable will be as it was in the beginning, and it *will* install packages globally (which is **not** what you want).

Comment: Many thanks. So is it right that: if I didn't use and activate virtual environment, then "pip install requests" would execute globally. If I had activated virtual environment (i.e., after enter command "my_env\Scripts\activate.bat"), then both "pip install requests" and "my_env\Scripts\pip.exe install requests" would execute locally (honestly, I kind of feel that using "pip install requests" is easier and hence better, am I right)?

Comment: @NicholasLiu yes you got it