# Distributing a large Python-enabled application: best practices

Tags: python, distribution, setuptools

There is a large Python application that consists of numerous third-party packages and binary libraries. Here is an overview of my requirements:

- Cross-platform (currently Windows and modern Linux distributions)
- Installing lots (say >100 MB) of binary libraries (DLLs on Windows)
- Installing third-party Python packages (some of them cannot be installed on Windows using tools like `easy_install`)
- Installing Visual Studio redistributable package it needed
- Preserving file layout for my package if possible (no compressed eggs)
- A clear way to remove all packages and libraries
- Distribute test suite (`py.test` in my case)
- Option for no-source distribution (`.pyc`-only)

The application should be "portable" at least as a Python package (can be installed anywhere using VirtualEnv).

What are my choices? Should I just stick with `setuptools` ([`distribute`](http://packages.python.org/distribute/))? Should I roll out custom installer?

The application being developed is proprietary, but it provides Python API for developers, and I want it to look and feel as pythonish and hackerish as possible.

Comment: So, what's the problem with using distribute?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155128/python-packages-installation-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

Py2Exe can done most of the prerequisites, and dependencies, to remove and additional install/uninstall you could use any msi installer creator.