# Find all packages installed with easy_install/pip?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, pypi

Is there a way to find all Python PyPI packages that were installed with easy_install or pip?  I mean, excluding everything that was/is installed with the distributions tools (in this case apt-get on Debian).

Comment: Related: [Listing installed python site-packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300794/)

Answer (score 403):

`pip freeze` will output a list of installed packages and their versions. It also allows you to write those packages to a file that can later be used to set up a new environment.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/#pip-freeze

Comment: As of Version 1.3 'pip list' has been added. See my answer below and the docs here: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-list

Comment: list and freeze output different formats (as of the time of writing). The freeze output can be used to recreate environments: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#other-notes

Comment: `pip freeze` and `pip list` list everything. They don't exclude the packages that weren't installed by `pip`.

Comment: I also find `pip freeze` to be reliable in scripts, whereas `pip list` will generate unexpected errors when being used with pipes.

Comment: The new (?) `pip list -l` or `pip list --local` is the best answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43012269/491884 by @MJB

Comment: This does not responds the question: list packages installed by PIP but NOT the installed with the distro packages

Answer (score 270):

As of version 1.3 of pip you can now use `pip list`

It has some useful options including the ability to show outdated packages. Here's the documentation: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_list/

Comment: On Gentoo, this lists *all* the packages, even those installed by other means than pip.  Does this really exclude non-pip installed modules on other system as requested by the question?

Comment: Note that this is slightly different from `pip freeze`

Comment: `pip list --user` only shows packages installed by the user, and excludes system-wide packages.

Comment: @JacobHume the `--user` flag makes pip install stuff to the user install directory. it will not list stuff installed with `sudo pip install packagexyz`.

Answer (score 139):

If anyone is wondering you can use the 'pip show' command.

```
pip show [options] <package>
```

This will list the install directory of the given package.

Answer (score 28):

Start with:

```
$ pip list
```

To list all packages. Once you found the package you want, use:

```
$ pip show <package-name>
```

This will show you details about this package, including its folder. You can skip the first part if you already know the package name

Click [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_show/) for more information on pip show and [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_list/) for more information on pip list.

Example:

```
$ pip show jupyter
Name: jupyter
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: Jupyter metapackage. Install all the Jupyter components in one go.
Home-page: http://jupyter.org
Author: Jupyter Development Team
Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.org
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: ipywidgets, nbconvert, notebook, jupyter-console, qtconsole, ipykernel
```

Comment: Best answer IMHO. Really simple and fast if I know the package name. pip list is not even necessary and freeze can take a long time and I have to filter out stuff I don't care about. Simple: pip show my_packge

Answer (score 26):

If Debian behaves like recent Ubuntu versions regarding `pip install` default target, it's dead easy: it installs to `/usr/local/lib/` instead of `/usr/lib` (`apt` default target). Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/173323/how-do-i-detect-and-remove-python-packages-installed-via-pip/259747#259747

I am an ArchLinux user and as I experimented with pip I met this same problem. Here's how I solved it in Arch.

```
find /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages -maxdepth 2 -name __init__.py | xargs pacman -Qo | grep 'No package'
```

Key here is `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, which is the directory pip installs to, YMMV. `pacman -Qo` is how Arch's **pac** kage **man** ager checks for ownership of the file. `No package` is part of the return it gives when no package owns the file: `error: No package owns $FILENAME`. Tricky workaround: I'm querying about `__init__.py` because `pacman -Qo` is a little bit ignorant when it comes to directories :(

In order to do it for other distros, you have to find out where `pip` installs stuff (just `sudo pip install` something), how to query ownership of a file (Debian/Ubuntu method is `dpkg -S`) and what is the "no package owns that path" return (Debian/Ubuntu is `no path found matching pattern`). Debian/Ubuntu users, beware: `dpkg -S` will fail if you give it a symbolic link. Just resolve it first by using `realpath`. Like this:

```
find /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages -maxdepth 2 -name __init__.py | xargs realpath | xargs dpkg -S 2>&1 | grep 'no path found'
```

Fedora users can try (thanks @eddygeek):

```
find /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages -maxdepth 2 -name __init__.py | xargs rpm -qf | grep 'not owned by any package'
```

Comment: +1 Thanks alot for the Arch one-liner, that's exactly what I was looking for. By the way, curious fact: my Arch installation is localized in italian, but grep correctly 'grepped' the lines that said 'Nessun pacchetto' (italian for 'No package') even though I grepped for 'No package'. How come?

Comment: @barraponto @NadirSampaoli grep does nothing in my case. Because grep try to grep in stdout, but `dpkg` write the error to stderr so i have to add a redirect `2>&1`. And for international output add `LANG= ` in front of `xargs dpkg -s`. and `sed` is also a nice tool ;) to keep only the package name of the path. So I end up with: `find /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages -maxdepth 2 -name __init__.py | xargs realpath | LANG= xargs dpkg -S 2>&1 | grep 'no path found' | sed "s/.*\/\([^\/]*\)\/__init__\.py.*/\1/"`

Comment: hi, I downvoted this by mistake and only just realised it, and now my vote's locked in. Could someone vote this up to neutralise my downvote? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Newer versions of pip have the ability to do what the OP wants via `pip list -l` or `pip freeze -l` (`--list`).
On Debian (at least) the man page doesn't make this clear, and I only discovered it - under the assumption that the feature must exist - with `pip list --help`.

There are recent comments that suggest this feature is not obvious in either the documentation or the existing answers (although hinted at by some), so I thought I should post. I would have preferred to do so as a comment, but I don't have the reputation points.

Comment: turns out we had `pip freeze --local` for 8 years. `pip list --local` is available too... but notice the OP question is not about virtual environments (which `--local` supports) but about discerning distro packages from `sudo pip install` packages.

Answer (score 8):

`pip.get_installed_distributions()` will give a list of installed packages

```
import pip
from os.path import join

for package in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    print(package.location) # you can exclude packages that's in /usr/XXX
    print(join(package.location, package._get_metadata("top_level.txt"))) # root directory of this package
```

Comment: This will not work anymore.  See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5243

Instead you should use:

import pkg_resources
[print(d.project_name) for d in pkg_resources.working_set]

Answer (score 7):

Adding to @Paul Woolcock's answer,

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

will create a **requirements file** with all *installed* packages along with the installed version numbers in the  active environment at the current location. Running

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

will install the packages specified in the requirements file.

Answer (score 6):

The below is a little slow, but it gives a nicely formatted list of packages that `pip` is aware of.  That is to say, not all of them were installed "by" pip, but all of them should be able to be upgraded by pip.

```
$ pip search . | egrep -B1 'INSTALLED|LATEST'
```

The reason it is slow is that it lists the contents of the entire pypi repo.  I filed a [ticket](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/795) suggesting `pip list` provide similar functionality but more efficiently.

Sample output: (restricted the search to a subset instead of '.' for all.)

```
$ pip search selenium | egrep -B1 'INSTALLED|LATEST'

selenium                  - Python bindings for Selenium
  INSTALLED: 2.24.0
  LATEST:    2.25.0
--
robotframework-selenium2library - Web testing library for Robot Framework
  INSTALLED: 1.0.1 (latest)
$
```

Comment: Why not file the ticket yourself?

Comment: Apparentlly the next version of pip will have a new list command: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-list

Answer (score 4):

Take note that if you have multiple versions of Python installed on your computer, you may have a few versions of pip associated with each.

Depending on your associations, you might need to be very cautious of what pip command you use:

```
pip3 list
```

Worked for me, where I'm running Python3.4. Simply using `pip list` returned the error `The program 'pip' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install python-pip`.

Comment: pip is for python2.7, pip3 is for python3.x

Answer (score 3):

As @almenon pointed out, this no longer works and it is not the supported way to get package information in your code. The following raises an exception:

```
import pip
installed_packages = dict([(package.project_name, package.version) 
                           for package in pip.get_installed_distributions()])
```

To accomplish this, you can import `pkg_resources`. Here's an example:

```
import pkg_resources
installed_packages = dict([(package.project_name, package.version)
                           for package in pkg_resources.working_set])
```

I'm on `v3.6.5`

Answer (score 2):

pip freeze lists all installed packages even if not by pip/easy_install.
On CentOs/Redhat a package installed through rpm is found.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the one-liner for fedora or other rpm distros (based on @barraponto tips):

```
find /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages -maxdepth 2 -name __init__.py | xargs rpm -qf | grep 'not owned by any package'
```

Append this to the previous command to get cleaner output:

```
 | sed -r 's:.*/(\w+)/__.*:\1:'
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all file/folder names in `site-packages/` (and `dist-packages/` if it exists), and use your package manager to strip the ones that were installed via package.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the **Anaconda** python distribution, you can use the `conda list` command to see what was installed by what method:

```
user@pc:~ $ conda list
# packages in environment at /anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py36h2fc01ae_0
alabaster                 0.7.10           py36h174008c_0
amqp                      2.2.2                     <pip>
anaconda                  5.1.0                    py36_2
anaconda-client           1.6.9                    py36_0
```

To grab the entries installed by `pip` (including possibly `pip` itself):

```
user@pc:~ $ conda list | grep \<pip
amqp                      2.2.2                     <pip>
astroid                   1.6.2                     <pip>
billiard                  3.5.0.3                   <pip>
blinker                   1.4                       <pip>
ez-setup                  0.9                       <pip>
feedgenerator             1.9                       <pip>
```

Of course you probably want to just select the first column, which you can do with (excluding `pip` if needed):

```
user@pc:~ $ conda list | awk '$3 ~ /pip/ {if ($1 != "pip") print $1}'
amqp        
astroid
billiard
blinker
ez-setup
feedgenerator
```

Finally you can grab these values and pip uninstall all of them using the following:

```
user@pc:~ $ conda list | awk '$3 ~ /pip/ {if ($1 != "pip") print $1}' | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Note the use of the `-y` flag for the `pip uninstall` to avoid having to give confirmation to delete.

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't have pip installed, I found this quick script on [github](https://gist.github.com/jldupont/1644406) (works with Python 2.7.13):

```
import pkg_resources
distros = pkg_resources.AvailableDistributions()
for key in distros:
  print distros[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

pip list [options]
You can see the complete reference [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/)

Comment: This is the same as [2nd highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16759140/2745495).

Answer (score 0):

At least for Ubuntu (maybe also others) works this (inspired by a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15024813/1961303) in this thread):

```
printf "Installed with pip:";
pip list 2>/dev/null | gawk '{print $1;}' | while read; do pip show "${REPLY}" 2>/dev/null | grep 'Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages' >/dev/null; if (( $? == 0 )); then printf " ${REPLY}"; fi; done; echo
```

Answer (score 0):

**pip list:**

```
pip list
```

This will get the list of installed packages along with their version in angular braces

pip List has multiple options like

1. List outdated packages

   ```
      python -m pip list --outdated
   ```

This will List all outdated packages installed in python.

2. List all updated packages

   ```
   python -m pip list -u
   ```

This will list all package that are upto date.

3. List outdated packages with no dependencies

   ```
   python -m pip list --outdated --not-required
   ```

This will List all outdated packages that are not dependencies of other packages.

4. List all the packages in json format

   ```
   python -m pip list --format=json
   ```

For More details Refer : https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/list-packages-modules-installed-python/

**pip freeze:**

We can Also use

```
pip freeze
```

This will get the list of installed packages along with their version as shown below
[image]