# How can I tell if Python setuptools is installed?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm writing a quick shell script to make it easier for some of our developers to run Fabric.  (I'm also new to Python.)  Part of installing Fabric is installing pip, and part of installing pip is installing setuptools.

Is there any easy way to detect if setuptools is already installed?  I'd like to make it possible to run the script multiple times, and it skip anything it's already done.  As it stands now, if you run ez_setup.py twice in a row, you'll get a failure the second time.

One idea I had was to look for the easy_install scripts under the /Scripts folder.  I can guess at the Python root using sys.executable, and then swap off the executable name itself.  But I'm looking for something a little more elegant (and perhaps cross-OS friendly).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to import easy_install, if it throws an error your way - it's not there :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't great but it'll work.

A simple python script can do the check

```
import sys
try:
    import setuptools
except ImportError:
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    sys.exit(0)
```

OR

```
try:
    import setuptools
except ImportError:
    print("Not installed.")
else:
    print("Installed.")
```

Then just check it's exit code in the calling script

Answer (score 27):

Try with this command.

```
$ pip list
```

It returns the versions of both `pip` and `setuptools`. Otherwise try with

```
$ pip install pil
```

If this also doesn't work, then try with

```
$ which easy_install
```

Comment: Does `pip list` work? In my system its giving a command not found error. Also check out the Markdown syntax in edit help to see what options are available for editing.

Comment: Seems I'm running an older pip. `pip list` is available with pip 1.3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600878/find-all-packages-installed-with-easy-install-pip

Comment: Yes, it works. Being an installable package, you may want to know the setuptools version inside your virtualenv.

Answer (score 4):

Just run the following code into IDLE:

```
import easy_install
```

If  it just goes to the next line, I think it's installed.
If it says:

```
Error: invalid syntax
```

Then it probably isn't installed.
I know this because I tested pip with it.
Also just check `import pip` to see if pip is pre-installed. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can check for easy_install and setuptools by running the following command line commands:

```
which easy_install
#finds the path to easy_install if it exists

less path/to/easy_install
#where path/to/easy_install is the output from the above command
#this outputs your easy_install script which will mention the version of setuptools
```

If the easy_install/setuptools bundle is installed, your output from the second command above will probably read something like this:

```
#EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'setuptools==0.6c11','console_scripts','easy_install'
```

Answer (score 2):

It comes preinstalled with new versions of Python.

```
pip3 list
```

was enough to identify it was installed for me

Comment: Did not come preinstalled for me when installing from source

Answer (score 2):

This will display the version of your setuptools if it is installed already

`$python -c "import sys; import setuptools; print(setuptools.version.__version__)"`

Answer (score 0):

Depends with the python version installed. you can try `"pip list"` or `"pip3 list"` and check for the setuptools and version installed.