# How to know what packages are installed with pip

Tags: python, windows, pip

I have Python installed in Windows and used `pip` to install lots of things.

How can I know what packages I installed with `pip`?

Comment: @PeterWood I guess it means `pip install`-ed. `pip freeze` will show the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all packages installed with pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600878/find-all-packages-installed-with-easy-install-pip)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`pip list` will list all your installed packages.

Comment: What if there is more than one version of Python installed?

Comment: @PeterWood `python -m pip list` will work, and you can change `python` to the version you need.

Comment: I've got google cloud bigquery installed, but it's not showing in the list