# Get the list of packages installed in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

Over a period of time, I have loaded a number of packages into the Anaconda I have been using. Now I am not able to keep track of it. How do we get a list of all packages loaded in Anaconda (Windows 10)? What is the command?

Comment: I don't know about Anaconda specifically, but for generic Python, third-party packages are usually installed in the site-packages folder.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

in terminal, type : `conda list` to obtain the packages installed using conda.

for the packages that `pip` recognizes, type : `pip list`

There may be some overlap of these lists as `pip` may recognize packages installed by `conda` (but maybe not the other way around, IDK).

There is a useful source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600878/find-all-packages-installed-with-easy-install-pip), including how to update or upgrade packages..

Comment: Is there a way to list only top-level packages. Under top-level I mean those that aren't installed as a dependency of another package.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no easy way to do that @handras

Comment: @handras, now there is. From the [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-an-environment-file-across-platforms): "If you want to make your environment file work across platforms, you can use the `conda env export --from-history` flag. This will only include packages that you’ve explicitly asked for, as opposed to including every package in your environment."

Answer (score 37):

To list all of the packages in the active environment, use:

```
conda list
```

To list all of the packages in a deactivated environment, use:

```
conda list -n myenv
```

Comment: `conda list` will not list packages in a deactivated environment... I wonder if there's a way to list packages in all environments... `conda list -n env1 -n env2` lists `env2` and ignores `env1`.  Let me search that...

Comment: @PatrickT Hey, you can do it thanks to bash `for ENV in $(conda env list | grep -v "^#" | awk '{print $1}') ; do conda list -n $ENV >> allEnvironments.txt ; done`

Answer (score 28):

To check if a specific package is installed:

```
conda list html5lib
```

which outputs something like this if installed:

```
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0
```

or something like this if not installed:

```
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
```

you don't need to type the exact package name. Partial matches are supported:

```
conda list html
```

This outputs all installed packages containing 'html':

```
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0
```

Comment: The environment must be activated for that to work (at the time of writing anyways).

Answer (score 13):

To list all of the packages in the active environment in a format that resembles `pip freeze`:

```
conda env export
```

Example of output:

```
name: pytorch
channels:
  - pytorch
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8.5=h7579374_1
  - python_abi=3.8=1_cp38
  - pytorch=1.7.1=py3.8_cuda11.0.221_cudnn8.0.5_0
  - pytorch-lightning=1.1.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tensorboard=2.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pip:
    - bert-score==0.3.7
    - tokenizers==0.9.4
    - transformers==4.2.1
prefix: /home/franck/anaconda3/envs/pytorch
```

You can save the environment and re-create and/or reactivate it:

```
# Save the environment
conda env export > my_conda_env.yml

# Re-create the environment
conda env create --file my_conda_env.yml

# Reactivate the environment
conda activate pytorch
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you here but it seems your Twitter account is hacked.

Comment: @ayhan crap I'll look into it now

Comment: @ayhan password reset and spam tweets removed, thanks very much! Bad coincidence and bad security practice from Twitter made me think the Twitter email about connection warning was me (why would Twitter say "connection from the US" in their connection warning without giving a more precise address or IP... dumb!). https://tweetdelete.net/ was very handy btw to clean spam tweets!

Comment: Yeah that's not very informative for a suspicious login. Glad you got it back without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

For more conda list usage details:

```
usage: conda-script.py list [-h][-n ENVIRONMENT | -p PATH][--json] [-v] [-q]
[--show-channel-urls] [-c] [-f] [--explicit][--md5] [-e] [-r] [--no-pip][regex]
```

Answer (score 1):

For script creation at Windows cmd or powershell prompt:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
conda list
pip list
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can see what conda has installed from the history file in your conda environments meta directory. It's located in $ENV_PATH/conda-meta/history. This will tell you the commands that have run for that environment so should list the explicit specs that you directly installed

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8986#issuecomment-572736603

Just have a look for the lines starting with "# cmd:" which further contain "install".
For Windows the path to the history file may start with `%env_path%` instead of `$ENV_PATH`.