# No module found error for every conda package in anaconda jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

After installing the latest scikit-learn version (19) using conda in Anaconda Jupyter, all packages are showing `ModuleNotFoundError` - scikit learn, numpy, matplotlib, etc. This is happening for all conda packages. After uninstalling and reinstallling, I have the same problem.

My kernel specs :

```
sana@skb-linux:~$ . activate my_env
(my_env) sana@skb-linux:~$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /home/sana/anaconda3/envs/my_env/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

My code:

```
# scipy
import scipy
print('scipy: %s' % scipy.__version__)
```

Result:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-73263c49dde4> in <module>()
      1 # scipy
----> 2 import scipy
      3 print('scipy: %s' % scipy.__version__)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

[image]

Comment: Did you install those and open Jupyter notebook in the same environment or working in a different environment?

Comment: How did you install those packages? Using pip or conda?

Comment: in same enviroement my_env bcz i have only one environment that i created while installing anaconda

Comment: i have installed all the pakages using conda only @vivek

Comment: i created my environment
conda create --name my_env python=3

Comment: problem solved but warning issues with import sklearn warning
/home/sana/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py:4: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
  from collections import Sequence
kindly solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final solution: first need activate the environment you are working  and install conda package in that particular environment using conda install and do need not to install outside of your environment

```
sana@skb-linux:~$ . activate my_env
(my_env) sana@skb-linux:~$ conda install scikit-learn
Solving environment: done
```

so the sklearn package is installed in your particular environment(in my case its installed my_env)

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the install packages by typing `!conda list` in the notebook and check for scikit-learn package is there or not.
If it's not present then you can install it by `!pip install scikit-learn` or `!conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn`

later try `import sklearn` it should work!.

There is a useful source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600878/find-all-packages-installed-with-easy-install-pip), including how to update or upgrade packages..

Comment: yes all packages are install are shown in terminal conda list
# packages in environment at /home/sana/anaconda3
scikit-learn              0.19.1
same for numpy matplotlib scipy

Comment: in every package i am importing casing same module problem

Comment: I have done fresh installation again showing same problem

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: linux-ubuntu 18

Comment: i got the solution in above answer i posted ....but got some warning issues  when iwrite import sklearn the warning is - /home/sana/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py:4: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
  from collections import Sequence
kindly help in this

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on installing jupyter through conda, tried a lot of things, didn't work out. Finally, I remove it and re-installed it, worked fine this time, lol!!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31586880)