# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.misc.pilutil'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am not able to import scipy.misc.pilutil

Though I have pillow and scipy installed. I am able to import scipy.misc but can't use functions like imresize

```
from scipy.misc.pilutil import imresize

ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-20-a7ba6cfb7450> in <module>()
----> 1 from scipy.misc.pilutil import imsave

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.misc.pilutil'
```

Comment: What version of scipy do you have? Works for me on scipy 1.1.0

Comment: @ItamarMushkin I am using scipy 1.3.0 ant the version of pillow is 6.1.0

Comment: @meghnakapoor do you have multiple installs of python or virtual environments?  If that is the case make sure you are running the intended python version and / or virtual environment.

Comment: @Mr.Radical I am using google colab and I don't have any other environment there.

Comment: @meghnakapoor I found this on how to install a package in colab: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342408/how-do-i-install-python-packages-in-googles-colab#51343539. Basically you need to prepend each pip command with !. So maybe you could try `!pip list`to show a list of packages you installed (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600878/find-all-packages-installed-with-easy-install-pip).  It worked for me with jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because you are using scipy v1.3.0 and imresize() is deprecated.
Also make sure you have Pillow installed.

See here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html

*"imresize is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.3.0."*

Either downgrade to v1.2.x or use Pillow resize() instead: numpy.array(Image.fromarray(arr).resize()).

Answer (score 0):

Check your scipy version. I had the same issue and after I've changed the scipy version to 1.1.0. the issue disappeared.

To check the scipy version in the terminal:

```py
import scipy 
scipy.version.full_version
```

Answer (score 0):

The newer version of scipy has removed the `imsave` and many other functions such as `resize`, you can install older version of scipy with following:

```py
pip install scipy==1.1.0
```